# Metasploitable file system error (fsck); and msfadmin root password not working

Tags: linux, password, root, fsck, metasploit

encountered this on Metasploitable 2 **Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue):** The default root password of **msfadmin** isn't working. It keeps saying login incorrect.

[image: ?]

Please what is the correct password and how do I resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Please do not post text as pictures. It repulses people that may answer. See https://xkcd.com/2116/.

The password `msfadmin` is not the default root password. It is the password for the user `msfadmin`.

To access `root`, you need to set the `root` password. `sudo passwd root` when you are logged in as `msfadmin` should work.

As for the point where you're stuck: read the message. It says:

> Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue):

As you don't have the `root` password, use the other option, control-d.

If the control-d does not help, i.e. it just reboots and comes with the same prompt, you should download a newer image of metasploitable.

Comment: Dullarart thanks for your response. Sorry about the text as picture, noted. Using Control-D only restarts the machine with the same issue.